# Reproducing VB6 Forms

Tags: graphics

I have searched google for 2 days - so sorry if you think this is a duplicate.

The attached is a jpg from a screen dump of a form created in Visual Basic 6.
I need to get a very similar drawing/picture into LaTeX without loss of quality.
Being new to LaTex, I am finding it very difficult to get a template.

Any/all thoughts appreciated.

Cheers.

[image: Visual Basic Form]

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "very similar" and "without loss of quality"? Is there a reason why you do not want to use `\includegraphics{screenshot.jpg}`? (I would suggest saving the screenshot in png anyway)

Comment: @Mark Tucker - Do you want to include a screenshot or do you want to construct a similar image yourself?

Comment: I have the screenshot. I have tried    \includegraphics{screenshot.jpg}  and  \includegraphics{screenshot.png}  and both look like they were drawn by a 3-year old using blunt crayons.  I want to recreate the image myself (maybt \begin{picture} BLAH \end{picture}).  By "very similar", I mean exactly the same layout, but I don't care about the fading of the blue colour bar along the top. Cheers

Comment: Could you show us the result of `\includegraphics`? You sure can draw a layout for GUI. Check TikZ, PSTricks, or Asymptote. There is also mockup software that can do it more easily and which export to vector formats (hence the quality is optimal).